# How to use two classes on one element

Tags: html, css

I have the following two CSS components:

```
#enableScrolling {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100vh;
}

#grey {
    background-color: #F0F0F0 !important;
}
```

I would like to use them together in an HTML tag.

I would like to do something like this:

```
#greyScrolling {
    .enableScrolling
    .grey
}
```

Otherwise, I would like to bring them together in a tag directly, like this:

```
<div id='enablescrolling' ???='grey>
```

How can I combine these two components?

Comment: not possible with regular css. it's not "code". there's no way to "program" this sort of thing. there's various CSS preprocessors/compilers you can use to do this kind of thing, but all they do is take their own metasyntax and spit out what would amount to your original css anyways.

Answer (score 2):

You can use classes instead of id's:

```
.enableScrolling {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100vh;
}

.grey {
    background-color: #F0F0F0 !important;
}
```

And then add them both to the div:

```
<div class="enableScrolling grey"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a class names instead of IDs and combine the CSS declarations in one class:

HTML:

```
<div class="class-name">
```

CSS:

```
.class-name {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #F0F0F0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make them both classes instead;

```
.enableScrolling {
     overflow-y:scroll
     height: 100vh;
}

.grey {
    background-color: #F0F0F0 !important;
}
```

Then just call

```
<div class="enableScrolling grey> Content ... </div>
```

This works because an element can have many classes simultaneously. You current have your styling set as `ID` and according to the "rules" an element can have only 1 `ID` and that `ID` can only be used once per page.